# List Comparison including Index

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
array_one = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array_two = [6, 7, 1, 2, 17, 23, 3, 48, 4]

lc = [e for e in array_one if e in array_two]
```

So far so good, I find the values that I want. Next important step for me is to get the index of the found items.

I tried

```
lc_2 = [index for index, (e1, e2) in enumerate(zip(array_one, array_two)) if e1 == e2]
```

but the results are not that what I need or I don't understand them right.

Long story short: It would be nice to find the duplicate items with corresponding indexes.

It have to be a flexible system, because in some cases I have 2 matches, sometimes 3, sometimes 1 a.s.o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values in `array_two` are unique, you can use [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=index) to find the index of the values in `array_one` in `array_two`. For example, this list comprehension will produce a list of tuples of (value, index in array_one, index in array_two) for each of the values in `array_one` that are also in `array_two`:

```py
array_one = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array_two = [6, 7, 1, 2, 17, 23, 3, 48, 4]

lc_2 = [(e, i, array_two.index(e)) for i, e in enumerate(array_one) if e in array_two]

print(lc_2)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 0, 2), (2, 1, 3), (3, 2, 6), (4, 3, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in numpy:

```
import numpy
values, indices_one, indices_two = numpy.intersect1d(array_one, array_two, return_indices=True)
```